# Strike rotation during a six

Tags: rules, cricket

When a batsman scores a six, can he rotate the strike? Will he get the six runs and also the strike rotated?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, The strike can only be rotated it the batsman actually run between the wickets thats what they only **rotate strike for the ODD number of runs made**, 6 is an even number so the batsman who hit the run remains on the strike.

**The situation is different if the batsmen hits a six on the last of the over, then indefinitely the batsmen men have to change the strike due to the completion of the over**

> "Switching of batting and bowling ends after every over is done to
> make the game fair and reduce any advantage due to external factors
> such as:
>
> Wind direction (which might support the batsman or the bowler) Ground
> dimensions (the ground might have certain boundaries shorter or longer
> than the others) Pitch conditions (batting continuously on one side
> might degrade the pitch from that end; one side might have more spin
> or bounce than the other)" In which the batsman doesn’t change the
> side the bowler does.

Comment: Hi Akhil- it looks like you're quoting the rules.  Can you link to them?  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe you can look for law 17.6 in Mcc laws which  you can find here [link](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/the-over)